# SQL Server 2008 Backup to networked drive

Tags: windows-7, sql-server, sql-server-2008

When I go to backup a SQL database - I only see options to do the backup on a local disk.

Is it possible to backup to a network drive directly?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You can either do it using t-sql or by just typing in the unc path (`\\server\share\folder\file.ext`).  There is no browse dialog or anything to help you find the path.  Part of the reason for that is that the backup runs under a different account than the dialog does, so access to any network paths can't be determined by the dialog.